# How can I make evenly tabbed list in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing

I want to make a list which currently looks like this

```
Hystérie Connective 3:09
Ghetto  2:41
Clé De Contact  2:50
```

to look like this

```
Hystérie Connective 3:09
Ghetto              2:41
Clé De Contact      2:50
```

How can I automate this process in Notepad++? I tried using Regex and extended mode but couldn't make an exact formula for dealing with this. I deal with these types of lists (n=100 or more) on a daily basis

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots, edit your question and add example as text. Show also what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: @Toto I edited it, can you please take a look and tell if this is better?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do such thing with regex alone. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

- Select *Plugins > Plugins Admin* and install [Code alignment](https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment)
- Separate the time with the title by a special separator that occurs nowhere in the file, for example `=`:

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to replace, switch to regex mode
  - Find what: `\s+([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})$`
  - Replace with: `=\1`
  - Replace All
- Select *Plugins > Code alignment > Align by equals*
- Replace the separator (`=`) with a space

You can use tab as a separator so that you can skip the last replacement step. You can also use any other strings like `abcde` as a separator, just remember to select the appropriate *Align by* entry in the *Code alignment* menu

Comment: I tried this, the align by equals didn't work as flawlessly as I had hoped. This is the output I am getting
<br/>
`Hystérie Connective =3:09  
Ghetto               =2:41  
Clé De Contact      =2:50`

But don't worry anyways because I had found a third party software that generates the list pre-aligned in the first place

Comment: I know. Unfortunately the plugin as some bugs regarding non-ASCII characters. I've filed a bug report. Until now it'll be useful to someone who only uses ASCII

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a bit different solution, that may as well work for you, but that which can you do with Regex. This will put the timestamp at the beginning of line instead of putting at the end.

**Search for:**

```
^(.*)\s+([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})
```

**Replace by:**

```
\2    \1
```

Here is how it will look like.

[image: notepad++ regex alignment]

**Some things to look out for:**

- you have posted only three lines, so there may be some discrepancies that may occur with larger set of text. Especially if you have numbers and special characters in them. You may have to tweak the regex in such cases.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works, but I found a software(FileListGenerator) that can do the task I wanted for me. Thank you anyways!